# Cloudinary widget: Setting resource type does not limit the type of files the user can upload

Tags: html, css, reactjs, cdn, cloudinary

According to the [documentation](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_widget#upload_preset_selection), this is how you limit the type of file the user can upload:

[image]

```
This is how I implemented it in my code:  
  var myWidget = window.cloudinary.createUploadWidget(
    {
      cloudName: "456aefaefaefayrw",
      uploadPreset: "dadazf",
      sources: ["local"],
      resourceType: "image",
    },
    (error, result) => {
      if (!error && result && result.event === "success") {
        console.log("Done! Here is the image info: ", result.info);
      }
    }
  );
```

But, the user can still see **ALL** types of files:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cloudinary allows uploading pdf as image type and videos when passed as `image` are uploaded as an image. You can use `clientAllowedFormats` option in the upload widget and that will block any other format from uploading other than the one specified or you can mention that in the upload preset.

Comment: That's rather strange. Thank you. It solved my problem/